# Экспорт div в excel со стилями

Tags: html, css, excel

Есть `<div id="page-wrap">` с несколькими разнородными таблицами.

Есть скрипт

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id=page-wrap]').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

И кнопка

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btnExport" value="Экспорт в Excel"/>
```

Экспорт происходит, но без стилей. Как пофиксить?

Comment: Задать стили явно через атрибут style.

Comment: либо сделать парсер, который будет смотреть в css файл и возвращать стили, которые применяются к объекту.